# In Mongoosejs, how to detect and set timeout for DB connection is lost?

Tags: node.js, database-connection, mongoose

if DB connection is lost, node will keep looking for the DB connection like crazy.

so, is there an option to set the # of connection retry, or timeout if connection lost? and throw errors.. instead of keep looping and trying to connect

mongoose.connect(db_path);

Comment: apparently, it is a node-mongo-native bug.

Answer (score 1):

This might not exactly answer you question but you can tell Mongoose to not try reconnecting by passing the `auto_reconnect` option to the server.  That will prevent it trying the DB automatically.

```
mongoose.connect(mongodb_url, { server : { auto_reconnect : true } });
```

Then in your code you could manually check for the connection state like this:

```
if ( mongoose.connection.readyState == 0 ) { // disconnected
   // reconnect
}
```

See other connection ready states: https://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose/blob/master/lib/connection.js#L38